# Interim Charging Order on Property was never changed to a Final Charging Order

Tags: united-kingdom, property, bankruptcy

If an Interim Charging Order on a property was never updated to a Final Charging Order can I get it removed? It has been over 13 years.

Edit to add more detail.

The creditor managed to sneak the interim charging order in the day before my bankruptcy hearing. So literally the very next day I was declared bankrupt. This was back in October 2009 and I am in England & Wales. I have not heard from the creditor since 2009, the debt has not been paid off, and as I say the interim charge was never made in to a final charge on the property title.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Exactly when was the charging order made? When was the CCJ applied for? Important procedural dates are 1 October 2012 and 1 October 2008, so "over 13 years" is not really precise enough. Have you paid off the debt? Also, are you in England & Wales or another jurisdiction within the UK?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have updated the question with some more detail. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I think that, with the bankruptcy being added to the question, the circumstances are unusual enough and complicated enough that you need legal advice which cannot be provided here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what has happened is the court has set aside, or refused to enter, a Final Charging Order because you were made bankrupt before the Final Charging Order could be issued.

In [Nationwide Building Society v Wright [2009] EWCA Civ 811](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2009/811.html) the Court of Appeal held that bankruptcy was a barrier to a Final Charging Order being issued if the bankruptcy commenced before the Final Charging Order could be issued. On the facts in your question, it is clear that no such Final Charging Order was issued before the bankruptcy commenced.

An Interim Charging Order will by necessity end unless a Final Charging Order is made. Since no such Order was made, it would seem that the Interim Charging Order has ended: the interim order is designed to stop someone from disposing of assets until the court can decide whether a final order is necessary. If no final order is made, the interim order dies with it.

A check on the Land Registry against the property would be needed to ensure that any notices or restrictions have been removed. If they are still present against the property's entry, an application to have them removed will have to be filed.

Furthermore, the Limitation Act 1980 provides a time limit of six or twelve years (cause of action dependent) for the creditor to take action to enforce their rights.

- In relation to enforcing judgments, the creditor has six years from the date of judgment to enforce it ([Section 24 of the Limitation Act 1980](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1980/58/section/24))
- In relation to recovering money secured by a charge or to recover the proceeds relating to a sale of land, the creditor has twelve years from the date that their right to receive the money started ([Section 20 of the Limitation Act 1980](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1980/58/section/20))

In either case, even if a Final Charging Order were able to be made in these circumstances, it is possible to argue that the relevant sections of the Limitation Act 1980 prevent the creditor from pursuing any right of action and so the debt (and any enforcement action) is statute-barred.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for such a thorough answer. Do you happen to know the process for requesting the removal of the order? Is there a simple form for me to fill out and send somewhere? Thank you again!